# Newbie- API to get Ethereum's latest blocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, ethereum

I am looking for an ethereum api to get the N latest blocks. I will use javascript (react) to make the requests.

I have looked into https://etherscan.io/apis#blocks but it has nothing to do with what I need (at least what I see there).

Also https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC seems complicated to use as I will have CORS issues (?). And I don't see what I need there either

Thank you

Comment: I think there is no such API for now, maybe you can try to use something like `getTransactionByBlock` then count the amount by yourself

Comment: @StillFantasy I was going to use https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/, getting the last block height, and then from there get the previous 10 blocks individually. I was expecting there to be an easier way, since it is what all block explorers have on their front page, but there seems not to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](https://docs.cinder.cloud/ethereum-get-latest-n-blocks) might be something you're looking for?

This returns latest-n blocks of the ethereum network. It's currently limited to 100 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

With Amberdata.io it's really easy you just:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://web3api.io/api/v2/blocks?size=10' \
  -H 'x-api-key: '
```

And it will give you the last 10 blocks. You can try it out [here](https://docs.amberdata.io/reference#get-all-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one from [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph?id=4oZC8eETdHshzyMySbvaXmH8p44E6wCbEYsKaFuijhRK&view=Overview) and change first 10 to value of N.

API Endpoint: [https://gateway.thegraph.com/api/[api-key]/subgraphs/id/4oZC8eETdHshzyMySbvaXmH8p44E6wCbEYsKaFuijhRK](https://gateway.thegraph.com/api/%5Bapi-key%5D/subgraphs/id/4oZC8eETdHshzyMySbvaXmH8p44E6wCbEYsKaFuijhRK)

> query last10Blocks {   blocks(first: 10, orderBy: BlockNum,
> orderDirection: desc) {
> BlockNum   } }